# sum for each customers and create a summary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, range

I have Table A  :

```
Customer_ID     Card_number   Amount_of_deals
      1             221            100
      1             222            350
      2             223            200
      3             334            700
      3             344            650 
      4             544            1500
```

I want to create a new table with ranges of the amount and count of customers in each range.
the new table should be :

```
Range      Number_of_customers
 0-500         2
 500-1000      0
 1000-1500     2
```

How can I create this table?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are uisng.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `case` expression with `group by` :

```
select (case when amount >= 0 and amount <= 500 then '0-500' 
             when amount > 500 and amount <= 1000 then '501-1000' 
             when amount > 1000 and amount <= 1500 then '1001-1500'
             else '1500+' 
        end) as Range, count(distinct custmore_id) as Number_of_customers
from table t
group by (case when amount >= 0 and amount <= 500 then '0-500' 
               when amount > 500 and amount <= 1000 then '501-1000' 
               when amount > 1000 and amount <= 1500 then '1001-1500' 
               else '1500+'
          end);
```

If you are using `SQL Server` then you can use `apply` & use `SELECT .. INTO` statement :

```
select range, count(distinct custmore_id) as Number_of_customers 
into new_table
from table t cross apply
     ( values (case when amount >= 0 and amount <= 500 then '0-500' 
                    when amount > 500 and amount <= 1000 then '501-1000' 
                    when amount > 1000 and amount <= 1500 then '1001-1500' 
                    else '1500+'
               end)  
     ) tt(range)
group by range;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! the second comment working great

Comment: @arnold . . . You accepted this answer but it dos not return `0` values.  In addition, it would return "1" for the 1000-1500 range.  That is not what your question specifies.

Comment: @arnold. . . If you want `0` for blank ranges then you should check `Gordon`s answer & accept if it helps you.

Comment: @GordonLinoff. . . Thanks. I didn't noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want `0` values, you need a `left join` somewhere.  I would recommend:

```
select v.range, count(c.customer_id)
from (values ('0-500', 0, 500),
             ('501-1000', 500, 1000),
             ('1001-1500', 1000, 1500)
     ) v(range, lo, hi) left join
     (select customer_id, sum(amount_of_deals) as num
      from a
      group by customer_id
     ) c
     on c.num > v.lo and c.num <= v.hi
group by v.range
order by min( v.lo );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=57f407b4e1c1b2e37a6f1e2fdfb278fd) is a db<>fiddle.